# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.impl.transformer.TransformerKey

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

i migrate from camel 2.23.4 to camel 3.14.7,
i fixed many errors folowing camel documentation of migration
but i keep getting this error when i lunch my back end application :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/impl/transformer/TransformerKey
 Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.impl.transformer.TransformerKey
```

After searching on internet, it seems this package  `org.apache.camel.impl.transformer.TransformerKey` is inside camel-base-engine dependency, so i added in my pom.xml:

```xml
<artifactId>camel-base-engine</artifactId>
```

My [back-end-log](https://easyupload.io/dbaqke)

My [main pom.xml](https://easyupload.io/816z22)

My [back end pom.xml](https://easyupload.io/8jecdk)